# Help on this surface integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, surfaces, surface-integrals

Calculate the following:

$$\int_S z \, dS$$

where S is the surface $$ z = x^2 + y^2 , x^2 + y^2 \le 1$$

Comment: Any work to show ? You need to show work to indicate to us what  you are struggling with, so we can give you a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a paraboloide of revolution defined in cylindrical coordinates by $$r=\sqrt {x^2+y^2}=\sqrt {z} $$
with $$0\le z \le 1.$$

the element of surface is
$$2\pi r dz =2\pi\sqrt {z}dz $$

the integrale is
$$2\pi\int_0^1z\sqrt {z}dz=$$
$$2\pi\frac {2}{5}=\frac {4\pi}{5} $$